# Trying to stop an embedded player from auto-playing using 'allowscriptaccess="always"'

Tags: flash

The embedded player I'm trying to stop auto-playing has the property 'allowscriptaccess="always"'. I'm trying to figure out how to set the property! In particular, I would like stop the the player from auto-playing on load up as this would make testing the website much easier.

Comment: AllowScriptAccess is present in both embed and object tags. Different browsers use different tags for flash content, so make sure you've got both setup properly. Can you be more explicit about autoplaying?

Comment: Yeah, the video starts playing automatically, very annoying when testing a homepage! hehe

Answer (score 0):

Confusing,

you have a swf and you want to stop autoplaying.
autoplaying ?
the timeline, some audio/video ?

do you have access to the fla ?
If not, do you know the structure of your swf ?

for timeline, all you need is a stop() call, which is easy peasy if you have the fla, if you only have the swf, the only thing that comes to mind is to make a new swf that either loads the original swf and in the Event.INIT handler on you loader's contentLoaderInfo's instance, do event.target.content.stop();

depending on what you use, you could embed that swf and access the original swf without any handlers and you'd end up with 1 swf in the end instead of 2.

Comment: The embed is using a blip.tv player, which I don't have direct control over. We just didn't want to have to ask the client to make another player on blip.

Comment: it would be great if there would be an API for the player, then you would know what methods to call to stop the player, etc.

If not, there's always the long way of loading the content, looping through the children, use describeType() to introspect instanced, etc.